# Displaying SSRS report on web page, which is not deployed on reporting server

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using visual studio 2008 and I want to display a SSRS report on web page using ReportViewer control. The report is not deployed on reporting server. Is it possible to display report using its physical path.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display reports with its physical path. You should be looking for RDLC reports. Below links gives you a detailed step-by-step procedure  to follow. Happy Coding....!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh166163(v=nav.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx